# How do I create a function in javascript that only allows letters, numbers, dashes -, underscores _ and spaces?

Tags: javascript, special-characters

I have to create a function that takes a string, removes all "special" characters (e.g. !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, , *, (, )) and
returns the new string. The only non-alphanumeric characters allowed are dashes -, underscores _ and spaces.

I'm new at this so I understand that this code may be ALL wrong.

```
module.exports = (str) => {
let allowedCharacters = [a-zA-Z0-9/s-_];
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    allowedCharacters += str[i]
}
return str[i];
};
```

Comment: Anything not working with the given code? If yes, what have you tried to resolve the problems?

Comment: You should use a forward slash `\\` instead of a backward slash.

Comment: it says that 'a' is not defined so I'm in research mode trying to figure out where i went wrong

Comment: @pilchard I used that structure because I found it in many of my google searches. I assumed it was to tell the console what characters are allowed. and then it assuming that all other characters not listed should not be in the new string

Comment: @WaisKamal I just switched it to a forward slash and my computer did not like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the string replace function with RegEx. Inside the parentheses you declare the characters that you want to allow `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` `-` and `_`. The `/g` stands for global and is used so that the replace won't stop at the first replaced character.

```js
let testString = '!@#$%^&*()+_- 33252qweqreteEWUJHGFA';
let resultString = testString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/g, '');

console.log(resultString);
```

Comment: What is "this? What did you change, and why? Keep in mind that a good explanation helps others to learn from your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use regex replacement:

```
let forbiddenCharacters = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s-_]", "g");
return str.replace(forbiddenCharacters, "");
```

Comment: OMG that worked!!! thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to help! Consider accepting this answer by clicking on the tick button.

Comment: it says i have to wait 2 mins to accept haha but i will!

Comment: question... why is the "g" there? just trying to understand because im new to coding. Wouldn't "g" be included in a-z?

Comment: `"g"` as the second parameter of the `RegExp` constructor is for making a global search. Without it, only the first illegal character would be replaced.

Comment: awesome thanks for explaining!